# Audience targeting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, audience-targeting

I have a page has 2 web parts where one web part is shared with some groups using target audience. I have added  content  web part saying the page is not shared with you. I want that content web part to be displayed only to people who are not added as target audience.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, you need to put people who are not added as target audience into a group, then set target audience for content web part through this group.